# Foundation 6 accordion 'collapse all/expand all' and scroll to top

Tags: jquery, zurb-foundation, accordion

I am looking to implement a 'expand all/collapse all' link for the accordion in Foundation 6.
For reference see this [codepen](https://codepen.io/Sp00ky/pen/zBZZvq).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".toggle-accordion").on("click", function() {
    var accordionId = $(this).attr("accordion-id"),
      numPanelOpen = $(accordionId + ' .collapse.in').length;
    
    $(this).toggleClass("active");

    if (numPanelOpen == 0) {
      openAllPanels(accordionId);
    } else {
      closeAllPanels(accordionId);
    }
  })

  openAllPanels = function(aId) {
    console.log("setAllPanelOpen");
    $(aId + ' .panel-collapse:not(".in")').collapse('show');
  }
  closeAllPanels = function(aId) {
    console.log("setAllPanelclose");
    $(aId + ' .panel-collapse.in').collapse('hide');
  }
     
});
```

```css
body {
  color: #6a6c6f;
  background-color: #f1f3f6;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.container {
  max-width: 960px;
}

.panel-default>.panel-heading {
  color: #333;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-color: #e4e5e7;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

.panel-default>.panel-heading a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 15px;
}

.panel-default>.panel-heading a:after {
  content: "";
  position: relative;
  top: 1px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  float: right;
  transition: transform .25s linear;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .25s linear;
}

.panel-default>.panel-heading a[aria-expanded="true"] {
  background-color: #eee;
}

.panel-default>.panel-heading a[aria-expanded="true"]:after {
  content: "\2212";
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.panel-default>.panel-heading a[aria-expanded="false"]:after {
  content: "\002b";
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.accordion-option {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  clear: both;
  margin: 15px 0;
}

.accordion-option .title {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  float: left;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.accordion-option .toggle-accordion {
  float: right;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #6a6c6f;
}

.accordion-option .toggle-accordion:before {
  content: "Expand All";
}

.accordion-option .toggle-accordion.active:before {
  content: "Collapse All";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="accordion-option">
    <h3 class="title">Lorem Ipsum</h3>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="toggle-accordion active" accordion-id="#accordion"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
  <div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
          Collapsible Group Item #1
        </a>
      </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
        <div class="panel-body">
          Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird
          on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table,
          raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
          Collapsible Group Item #2
        </a>
      </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
        <div class="panel-body">
          Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird
          on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table,
          raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingThree">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseThree">
          Collapsible Group Item #3
        </a>
      </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingThree">
        <div class="panel-body">
          Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird
          on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table,
          raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

(Separate 'expand all' and 'collapse all' links would be fine too.)

And also a way to implement a scroll to the top of a opened/active accordion.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

After initializing your accordion, you can achieve it with these functions:

```
// open all panels
$('#yourAccordion').foundation('down', $('#yourAccordion .accordion-content'));
// close all panels
$('#yourAccordion').foundation('up', $('#yourAccordion .accordion-content'));
```

Now you just need a click handler and a button/link to click on.

```
// HTML
<button id="#close" type="button">Collapse all</button>
<button id="#open" type="button">Expand all</button>
```

If you wish to use a link, don't forget to add `preventDefault()` and `return` in the click handler.

```
// js
$('#close').on('click', function () {
    $('#yourAccordion').foundation('up', $('#yourAccordion .accordion-content'));
})


$('#open').on('click', function () {
    $('#yourAccordion').foundation('down', $('#yourAccordion .accordion-content'));
})
```

Documentation: http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/accordion.html